# function definition with Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, web

I am trying one of the examples of the Extjs book. I want to define a function to show a message and run that function, so I copied the following code but it doesn't work. what's the problem with this?!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
        <script src="extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
        <script src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
        <script>
            Function stapler(){
                Ext.Msg.show({
                    title: 'Milton',
                    msg: 'Have you seen my stapler?',
                    buttons: {
                        yes: true,
                        no: true,
                        cancel: true
                    }
                });
            }
            Ext.onReady(stapler());
        </script>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

        <h1>Good Bye World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**`Function` should be lowercase `function`.

**2.**`Ext.onReady` should take a function as callback, not the result of the function.

`Ext.onReady(stapler());` should be `Ext.onReady(stapler);`